# Add extra element to a comma seperated list

Tags: java, arraylist

I have created an `ArrayList` from a comma separated string.  Now I want to add an extra blank space to this list, but I am getting following error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:131)
```

My Code is

```
inputParamList=Arrays.asList(inputVariablesNames.split(","));
inputParamList.add("");
```

Comment: `Arrays.asList` returns a fixed-size list, it's written in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks Alexis for you suggestion.But please let me know how can i achieve this.

Comment: You can google "java arrays aslist add" and you'll find the answer within seconds....

Answer (score 1):

The `List` returned by [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) is only a thin wrapper over an actual array, and you can't add elements to an array.

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.)

Convert it to an `ArrayList`. Then you can add the extra element to the `ArrayList`.

```
inputParamList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(inputVariablesNames.split(",")));
```